# PyFFTW Wisdom Planning Not Speeding Up Subsequent Calls on Larger Arrays

Tags: python, fftw, pyfftw

I am doing some timing calculations comparing

```
Method     Wisdom   Planning Effort
builder    None     FFTW_Estimate
FFTW core  None     FFTW_Estimate
FFTW core  Planned  FFTW_Estimate
```

I import the necessary packages:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit
import pyfftw
from collections import OrderedDict
```

Define individual functions for the above three test scenarios:

```
def builder_test(input_data, a):
    pyfftw.forget_wisdom()
    a[:] = input_data  # Assume input_data will always be new data
    fft_obj = pyfftw.builders.rfft(a, planner_effort='FFTW_ESTIMATE')
    return fft_obj()

def fftw_test(input_data, a):
    pyfftw.forget_wisdom()                  
    outLength = len(input_data)//2 + 1     
    outData = pyfftw.empty_aligned(outLength, dtype='complex64')
    fft_obj = pyfftw.FFTW(a, outData, flags=('FFTW_ESTIMATE',))
    a[:] = input_data  # Assume input_data will always be new data
    return fft_obj()

def fftw_test_planned(input_data, a, fft_obj):
    #a[:] = input_data  # Assume input_data will always be new data
    return fft_obj.__call__(input_array=input_data)

def wrapper(func, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Wrapper to call each function with timeit
    """
    def wrapped():
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
```

Then loop through various length arrays (`N`) and run the three tests on each using `timeit` (repeat each test 10 times and return the average time of the three fastest runs):

```
test_functions = OrderedDict([("FFTW", fftw_test), 
                              ("Builder", builder_test), 
                              ("FFTW-Planned", fftw_test_planned),
                             ])

N = [22829, 300013, 1124434, 1200048, 2465342, 3068583, 11553414, 17279800]

print("N  \tMin 3 Avg Time  \tFunction")  # Table header
for n in N:
    # Set up some byte aligned arrays for reuse 
    x = pyfftw.empty_aligned(n, dtype='float32', n=16)
    x[:] = np.random.uniform(-1000, 1000, [n])
    a = pyfftw.empty_aligned(n, dtype='float32', n=16)
    a[:] = x  # In the future, assume x would be constantly changing, may be shorter in length, etc
    outLength = len(a)//2 + 1
    outData = pyfftw.empty_aligned(outLength, dtype='complex64')

    for func_name in test_functions:
        # Wrap functions for timeit
        if 'Planned' in func_name:
            pyfftw.forget_wisdom()  # Forget wisdom before plan
            # For planned tests, create fftw_obj once before running repeated tests    
            #fft_obj = pyfftw.FFTW(a, outData, flags=('FFTW_MEASURE',), planning_timelimit=60.0)
            fft_obj = pyfftw.FFTW(a, outData, flags=('FFTW_ESTIMATE',))
            wrapped = wrapper(test_functions[func_name], x, a, fft_obj)
        else:
            # Wisdom is forgotten as first step within each unplanned function (see above)
            wrapped = wrapper(test_functions[func_name], x, a)

        # Timeit
        sorted_t = sorted(timeit.repeat(wrapped, number=1, repeat=10))  #Repeat timeit 10 times and sort
        min_3_t_avg = np.mean(sorted_t[:3])  # Average fastest three runs
        print("{}  \t{}  \t{}".format(n, min_3_t_avg, func_name))
    print("")
```

The results are as follows:

```
N        Min 3 Avg Time     Function
22829    0.00937143961589   FFTW
22829    0.00834314028422   Builder
22829    0.00342512130737   FFTW-Planned

300013   0.342160304387     FFTW
300013   0.333618402481     Builder
300013   0.0695606867472    FFTW-Planned

1124434  0.361418326696     FFTW
1124434  0.37025197347      Builder
1124434  0.306508302689     FFTW-Planned

1200048  0.506390889486     FFTW
1200048  0.507919232051     Builder
1200048  0.315515041351     FFTW-Planned

2465342  0.828966299693     FFTW
2465342  0.660408655802     Builder
2465342  0.637949228287     FFTW-Planned

3068583  0.936786015828     FFTW
3068583  0.942013422648     Builder
3068583  0.8645576636       FFTW-Planned

11553414 4.61405666669      FFTW
11553414 4.63671763738      Builder
11553414 4.39226007462      FFTW-Planned

17279800 4.76136477788      FFTW
17279800 4.8280433019       Builder
17279800 4.39278205236      FFTW-Planned
```

Initially, for the shorter arrays, it looks like the planned wisdom is working. However, as the array length gets longer, there is little difference in the results. I've even tried using `FFTW_MEASURE` with a 60 second `planning_timelimit` but the results are the same.

I've poured over the documentation but it looks like either I'm missing something with the wisdom planning or the planning isn't actually as effective/important as I'd expect.

**Before anybody recommends threading, I'd like to understand the value of wisdom planning first!**

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to test here. Perhaps you could clarify. Wisdom is just a way of storing knowledge about a particular transform so the planning step can be sped up. Planning can be time consuming, but generally the best strategy is try and not plan on-line, and that is what the wisdom is for.

Comment: @HenryGomersall I understand that wisdom can be saved/loaded. However, in my tests I am interested in timing within one session as the length of my arrays aren't known a priori. The FFTW and Builder tests are planned when called and is re-planned upon each repeat of the timeit call (note that the wisdom is purposely forgotten at the start of the functions). For the FFTW-planned test, planning is done once upon instantiation of the fftw object (for a given array length) and then the timeit repeat should be fast. Thus, I expect FFTW and Builder tests to be much slower than FFTW-planned.

Comment: @HenryGomersall Maybe I'm not understanding the planning docs. For a given array length, I want to plan once at the start by instantiating an `FFTW object` and then reuse that same plan within the same session (see `FFTW-Planned`). IIUC, I shouldn't have to save wisdom since the object keeps the plan until the end of the session and reuses the plan as long as the array length+stride is the same. `FFTW-Planned` must be faster than `FFTW` and `Builder` tests where a new `FFTW object` is instantiated for each repeat of `timeit` and a new plan is force to be created (`forget_wisdom()` is explicit)

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to test. Do you want to know the impact of the planning step? FFTW-Planned _is_ faster. What's the issue? You _have_ to plan - you can't avoid it. You can mostly eliminate the plan time by using wisdom if you've previously computed a plan (which can be saved between sessions). If your problem can be planned quickly, then congratulations. `FFTW_ESTIMATE` is much faster than the other options and results in a plan which is generally pretty good.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to understand the impact of planning once and reusing the plan vs planning before every run (sincerely, I am not trying to avoid planning). According to my results, for large arrays the FFTW and Builder tests (both with replanning at every repeat) is only marginally/imperceptibly slower than FFTW-planned. I guess I expected, say, a doubling in speed due to not having to re-plan but it looks like it's about 10% time savings by reusing a plan. Notice that timings for FFTW-Planned does not include any planning time while FFTW and Builder tests include planning time. No real diff

Comment: Well, `FFTW_ESTIMATE` is fast, so that's not unexpected. It's very difficult to _a priori_ estimate the planning cost. Moreover, there's quite an overhead in simply creating the plan in the first place, so irrespective of  the wisdom, you're going to suffer if you need to keep creating plans. What are you trying to do that has totally unknown vector lengths?

Comment: I have 10K+ different length arrays that each have 50K+ samples. For example, for one array length, `n`, I would have 50K+ samples (all with length `n`) for which to perform some convolution - `[irfft(rfft(x)*rfft(y)]`). I would need to loop over all of the different 10K+ sets of different array lengths and perform convolutions for their corresponding samples. I also tried `FFTW_MEASURE` with a 60s timelimit without much improvement. I also wanted to make sure I wasn't doing anything wrong. A 10% time savings is ok but that will be, say, 9 days of compute instead of 10 days.

Comment: Uhm, if you're doing a convolution then you only need one size that can contain all the others. If your lengths span orders of magnitude and you want to be cunning you could create a set of interim sizes of varying size that span your vector lengths with suitable lengths chosen for speed. You can always compute exactly the same result with some suitably constructed interim array.

Comment: For convolution, wouldn't I need one FFTW obj with dtype=float32 for the first two forward FFTs and one for dtype=complex64 for the inverse/backward FFT? I know I can do both forward/backward FFT with dtype=complex32 (though float32 would be faster) but can I use the same FFT obj for both forward/backward FFTs by simply changing the direction? Can I plan both forward and backward FFT and have them stored within the same FFT obj? Can you please provide an answer as an example? Also, if I use something slightly longer than my real length does that mean I'll need to pad my arrays with zeros?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136252/discussion-between-henry-gomersall-and-slaw).

Comment: I'm not sure what you were expecting. For large arrays and FFTW_ESTIMATE the planning cost is smaller than the execution cost. On my machine the cost is roughly even at around 100k array size.

If you want to transform either smaller arrays or want to make better plans with FFTW_MEASURE (or better) then you will see bigger benefits from working with wisdom, or even better just reusing the plan directly if possible.